# Combinatorics Question for Search Problem

Tags: combinatorics

I have an algorithm where I allocate integer values 1, ... , $m$ to $n$ positions, where $n \geq m$ with replacement (*i.e.*, repetition allowed). The $m$ values occur according to some probability distribution. Thus, some values of $m$ may be rare in a given sequence. To ensure that all $m$ values are seen at least once in the same sequence, I generate several runs of the $m$ values, each run of length $n$. Typically, the number of runs I generate is large, say, 10000.

As an example if I have the values 1, 2, 3, 4 and I want to assign these values to 4 positions, the possibilities I can end up with might be

2 1 3 3

4 4 2 1

2 1 1 1

*etc.*

It's been a while since I took a combinatorics class.

What I'm after is the size of the search space; that is, how many ways are there to arrange $m$ values into $n$ positions with repetition given that order doesn't matter (since I'm only interested in seeing all $m$ values in a sequence of length $n$ at least once).

So in the example I want to see one of the following

1 2 3 4

1 2 4 3

2 1 3 4

2 1 4 3

*etc.*

I have a feeling the answer is C(n + m - 1, m) = C(n + m - 1, n - 1), but think there is something more to it given the scenario at hand.

Can someone offer a way forward?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics) ?

Answer (score 1):

Stars & Bars is the way to go. You can consider $n$ values as  indistinguishable stars to be arranged in $m$ distinguishable bins. Note that the answer should be $${n+m-1}\choose n$$ and not ${n+m-1} \choose m$.